# Change default google places marker icon(POI) and size @react-google-maps/api

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps, next.js13

I am build in nextjs and I integrated google maps but my issue is the map is clumsy that is too many icons that look big. I have seen a taxi hailing app that displayed an circular and smaller icon. I need to be able to do that so when I display directions on my map it will not be confusing
[image]

Please help me with resources to achieve this since there is not extensive documentation on the package. If you can fix my code with some explanation.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  DirectionsRenderer,
  Circle,
  MarkerClusterer,
} from '@react-google-maps/api';
import { useMantineColorScheme } from '@mantine/core';
import { useLocation } from '@/app/dashboard-home/useLocation';
import { ICoordinates } from '@/interfaces/map';
import { ExposeRef } from '@/context/map-context';

type LatLngLiteral = google.maps.LatLngLiteral;
type DirectionsResult = google.maps.DirectionsResult;
type MapOptions = google.maps.MapOptions;

export default function Ground() {
  const [baseLocation, setBaseLocation] = React.useState<ICoordinates>();
  const { getUserLocation, errorMsg, loading } = useLocation();
  const { colorScheme } = useMantineColorScheme();
  const { mapRef } = React.useContext(ExposeRef) || {};

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchLocationInformation() {
      try {
        const userLocation = await getUserLocation();
        if (userLocation) {
          setBaseLocation(userLocation);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(errorMsg);
      }
    }
    fetchLocationInformation();
  }, []);

  const center = React.useMemo<LatLngLiteral | undefined>(
    () => (baseLocation ? { lat: baseLocation.latitude, lng: baseLocation.longitude } : undefined),
    [baseLocation]
  );

  const options = React.useMemo<MapOptions>(
    () => ({
      disableDefaultUI: false,
      clickableIcons: true,
      scrollwheel: true,
      mapId: colorScheme === 'dark' ? 'faaa827d36c66866' : '8660e06b8e3da749',
    }),
    [colorScheme]
  );
  const onLoad = React.useCallback((map: any) => {
    if (mapRef) mapRef.current = map;
  }, []);

  if (errorMsg) {
    return <div>{errorMsg}</div>;
  }
  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  const mapKey = colorScheme === 'dark' ? 'dark-map' : 'light-map';

  return (
    <>
      <GoogleMap
        key={mapKey}
        zoom={15}
        center={center}
        options={options}
        onLoad={onLoad}
        mapContainerStyle={{
          width: '100%',
          height: '87vh',
          position: 'relative',
          overflow: 'hidden',
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't change the size of default POI markers. But you can just turn their `visibility` off.

Comment: @Yrll So I am trying to do that and the lable also goes away.